# How can avoid a Javascript Timeout Exception when trying to open new browser window?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am currently facing the issue that when I run my test cases on a linux server, I receive a Timeout Exception when trying to open a new window with Robot Framework.

I only face this issue when the keyword is run on the server. When trying to reproduce the error locally, It almost never occurs.

The keyword consist of following steps:

```
Execute Javascript      window.open('')
Get Window Titles
Select Window           title=undefined
```

The keyword fails whenever it tries to run 'Execute Javascript   window.open('')'. the output I receive is as following:

`TimeoutException: Message: script timeout (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.79)`

I do use this keyword in 3 different test cases that are run in the same suite.

I checked different forums, but I can't really find the same issue as this one.

anyone who can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Don't have a Linux machine to test. Have you tried without the quotes in the Execute Javascript statement: `Execute Javascript      window.open()`

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `Get Window Titles` with retry:

`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    5x    1s    Get Window Titles`

This way, Robot will retry the keyword `5 times`, with a `1s` time interval between each try. If that also fails, something else might be wrong.